# How to Get the Length of an Array in Dafny?

Tags: arrays, dafny

How do I get the length of an array in dafny? I tried `arr.length`, `arr.size()`, and `arr.Length` and none of those worked. Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was somewhere else in my code. My problem had nothing to do with getting the array length. The correct way is `arr.Length`, by the way.